# Do constraints need to be binding for KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, problem-solving, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am testing that the point (1,0) satisfies KKT conditions for the following problem:

min (x1 − 2)^2+ 2(x2 − 1)^2

subject to

x1 + 4x2 ≤ 3

−x1 ≥ x2

Does it matter if the constraints are binding or not? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: It is unclear what you mean you are testing the point $(1,0)$ satisfying the KKT conditions since you also need to have dual variables (which are missing). Not sure what you mean by "does it matter if the constraints are binding". You can have cases where they bind and others where they don't. If the optimal point without the constraints is in the interior of the constraints then the constraints don't need to be binding.